# CGNAT port allocation

Tags: nat

I'm planning to implement CGNAT in service provider with a10 networks.
So, the question is how many private IP addresses I can NAT through one public IP ?

One public IP = 64511 ports = 400 ports per user = ~161 private addresses?

Is that right?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no hard limit. In theory, you can reuse a single L4 port for multiple connections, as long as either destination IP address or port number differs (a socket is defined by the tuple `source IP:source port:destination IP:destination port`.

Without re-using port numbers, each connection consumes one port, so it depends on how many connections you allow each client (like you've already calculated). If you do static allocations, a hard limit of 400 ports might not be enough though.

What you can actually do depends on your exact type of equipment and its configuration.